# Tensor contraction

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Given that:

$T_{i,j}=\lambda\theta\delta_{i,j} + 2\mu E_{i,j}$

Show that:

$T_{i,i} = 3\theta \lambda + 2\mu E_{i,i}$

I didn't get the intuition behind tensor contraction, thus i can not solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you give a definition of $E_{i,j}$ and of $\theta$? Moreover, can it be that you forgot a $\theta$ in your last line? I think that this problem is not about tensor contraction at all: there is no implicit summation in your last line.

Comment: What is $\theta$? What is the dimension of the space?

Comment: Yes, i forgot a $\theta$ in the last line. The problem doesn't inform what  $\theta$  is, but if i assume that is about a temperature field, and moreover, if i assume that $E_{ij}$ is a tensor.  Suppose we have a tridimensional space.The commas between the indices are not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply asking you to find the trace. One way of viewing this is writing your relation (which comes from Elasticity by the way) as
$$\boldsymbol{T} = \lambda\theta\boldsymbol{I} + 2\mu\boldsymbol{E}.$$
Then since for any second order tensor $\boldsymbol{A}$, the trace is defined by
$$\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{A}\right) = \boldsymbol{e}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{e}_j,$$
it is seen that 
$$\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{T}\right) = \lambda\theta\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{I}\right)+2\mu\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{E}\right).$$
Changing this last equation to component form gives the answer you seek since the definition of the trace in components (using the Einstein convention) is 
$$ \text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{A}\right) = A_{ii}.$$

Note that this is the familiar definition of the trace as the sum of the diagonal entries.